# Are resolve and reject in Javascript promises methods or just some variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, es6-promise

take the below example code

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
const x = "geeksforgeeks"; 
const y = "geeksforgeeks"
if(x === y) { 
    resolve(); 
} else { 
    reject(); 
} 
}); 

promise. 
    then(function () { 
        console.log('Success, You are a GEEK'); 
    }). 
    catch(function () { 
        console.log('Some error has occured'); 
    });
```

The above code works fine. But if I just execute the function that is passed as argument to Promise(),I get an error saying resolve is not a function.

```
(function(resolve, reject) { 
const x = "geeksforgeeks"; 
const y = "geeksforgeeks"
if(x === y) { 
  resolve(); 
} else { 
  reject(); 
} })()
```

if i run the above code, i get the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: resolve is not a function
```

Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: They are methods of a `Promise` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @ScottMarcus No, the two resolver functions passed to the executor callbacks are not methods.

Comment: In Javascript (independent of promises), you can't just make up arguments for a function and expect them to be valid unless whoever calls the function passes those arguments.  In your second example, nothing is passed to your function so naturally `resolve` and `reject` are `undefined`.  In the normal promise usage, the internals of `new Promise()` will pass a function for both the `resolve` and `reject` arguments.  So, when you call them, you're calling the function that the `new Promise()` constructor passed to your callback.  Your second code example doesn't pass anything to the function.

Comment: I see the confusion explained by jfriend00, but I don't really understand the OP's logic.  Is there a language where you can have an anonymous function automatically populate parameters as callable functions taken from a built-in's internal variables (or in this case private non-exposed methods)?

Comment: @Bergi I misunderstood the question. I wasn't referring to the functions that are passed. I was referring to the `Promise` API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resolve` and `reject` come from `Promise` objects, but they aren't methods. The `Promise` constructor sort of looks like this:

```js
class Promise {
  // handler should look like (resolve, reject) => {}
  constructor(handler) {
    function resolve(value) { /***/ }
    function reject(err) { /***/ }

    handler(resolve, reject);
  }
}
```

When you call `new Promise(handler)` with a handler of type function, the handler gets
called with two functions. When you call the same handler with no arguments, the handler
tries to call `undefined` and that's why you see the TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the function is called by the `Promsie` object with the required parameters `resolve` and `reject`, which would be functions.

The reason it does not work in your second case, where you immediately invoke the function, is because you are not passing the functions to the invocation:

```
(function(resolve, reject) { 
const x = "geeksforgeeks"; 
const y = "geeksforgeeks"
if(x === y) { 
  resolve(); 
} else { 
  reject(); 
} })(resolveFunctionHere, rejectFunctionHere) <----- HERE
```